# Magento 2 Adding Extension Attribute to Quote_Item

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, custom-options, extension-attributes

I am trying to add an extension attributes to `quote_item`. I have a plugin that works perfectly well when I add a simple item to `quote_item`, converting it from `quote_item` to `order_item`, and when I  an `order_item/order`.
However, when I try to add a configurable product to a cart, the plugin becomes a mess. I keep getting the `You need to choose options for your item.` error even though I have set my `custom_option`. and I am sure that they are all correct.

Any leads on this? I have searched everywhere and have not found a solution.

Here is my body of POST API call for adding a configurable product as a quote item:

```
{
  "cartItem": {
    "sku": "sweater_001",
    "qty": 1,
    "quote_id": "43",
    "product_type" : "configurable",
    "product_option": {
      "extension_attributes": {
        "configurable_item_options": [
          {
            "option_id": "93",
            "option_value": 4
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "extension_attributes":{}
  }
}
```

and here is the configurable product options of the product i am trying to add (retrieved using ../configurable-product/{sku}/options/all API:

```
[
    {
        "id": 6,
        "attribute_id": "93",
        "label": "Color",
        "position": 0,
        "values": [
            {
                "value_index": 4
            },
            {
                "value_index": 6
            }
        ],
        "product_id": 15,
        "options": [
            {
                "value_index": "4",
                "label": "black",
                "product_super_attribute_id": "6",
                "default_label": "black",
                "store_label": "black",
                "use_default_value": true
            },
            {
                "value_index": "6",
                "label": "red",
                "product_super_attribute_id": "6",
                "default_label": "red",
                "store_label": "red",
                "use_default_value": true
            }
        ],
        "product_attributes": {
            "attribute_id": 93,
            "attribute_code": "color",
            "frontend_input": "select",
            "entity_type_id": "4",
            "is_required": false,
            "options": [
                {
                    "label": " ",
                    "value": ""
                },
                {
                    "label": "black",
                    "value": "4"
                },
                {
                    "label": "blue",
                    "value": "5"
                },
                {
                    "label": "red",
                    "value": "6"
                }
            ],
            "is_user_defined": true,
            "default_frontend_label": "Color",
            "frontend_labels": null,
            "backend_type": "int",
            "backend_model": "Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Attribute\\Backend\\DefaultBackend",
            "source_model": "Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Attribute\\Source\\Table",
            "default_value": "",
            "is_unique": "0",
            "validation_rules": []
        }
    }
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hadn't your extension attributes required ??

Comment: You need to provide the custom child option product (simple product associated with parent configurable product).

Comment: @HoangHieu what do you mean by that?

Comment: @AnshuMishra I have added a code block of my POST request body. I believe it is correct according to magento's documentation.